# Android- Custom listview using BaseAdapter not displaying anything

Tags: listview, baseadapter

There are similar questions but none of the solution helped. And I think the problem is with the layout file or, the adapter class but couldn't find the error.
The Fragment loads up fine, but there is nothing in the list view.

---

### FavouritesFragment.java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class FavoritesFragment extends android.app.Fragment {




String namearray[];
String phonearray[];
String namecsv;
String phonecsv;
ListView lvl;
public static FavoritesFragment newInstance()
{
    FavoritesFragment fragment = new FavoritesFragment();
    return fragment;
}

public FavoritesFragment() {}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ((NavigationActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(4);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorites, container, false);

    lvl = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewFavourite);

    Cursor phones = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null, null);
    while(phones.moveToNext())
    {
        //read contact name
        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

        //read contact phonenumber
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

      if(name!=null)
      {
          namecsv += name +",";
          phonecsv+=phoneNumber +",";
      }

    }

    phones.close();

    namearray = namecsv.split(",");
    phonearray= phonecsv.split(",");

    namearray = removeDuplicate(namearray);
    phonearray = removeDuplicate(phonearray);


    // ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namearray);
    ListAdapter theAdapter = new FavouriteAdapter(getActivity(), namearray, phonearray);

    lvl.setAdapter(theAdapter);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),namecsv, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    lvl.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String number = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    });
    return rootView;
}



public String[] removeDuplicate(String[] str)
{
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str);
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
    String[] res = new String[set.size()];
    set.toArray(res);
    return res;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



}


}
```

---

### favourites.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewFavourite"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

---

### rowlayoutfavurite.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewContactName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewPhoneNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Text View"
     />

 </LinearLayout>
```

---

### FavouriteAdapter.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FavouriteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

String[] name;
String[] phone;
Context context;

  public FavouriteAdapter(Context cntxt, String[] valuename, String[] phonevalue)
  {
  super();
   name = valuename;
   phone=phonevalue;
   context = cntxt;

  }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View theView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowlayoutfavorite, parent, false);

TextView nameTextView = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textViewContactName);
TextView numberTextView = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPhoneNumber);
nameTextView.setText(name[position].toString());
numberTextView.setText(phone[position].toString());
return theView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return 0;
}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by your implementation of `getCount()`. This method is called by some part responsible for displaying the list on screen. As you are returning zero, the list seems to be empty, and that's it.

Change your method:

```
@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return name.length;
}
```